# How to get messages from Multiple sources with RxJava in Android

Tags: android, rx-java

I have chat application. I want to build Message Manager for my chat like in picture below.
Basically I have ChatActivity that displays messages. In ideal way I want to feed my ChatActivity with messages from MessageManager in this order.

1. Show 20 latest messages from local database.
2. If user scrolls, get another 20, and so on.
3. If no messages in local database, fetch messages from server, by offset.
4. Also new messages may come via socket(or push like in picture).

I know that RxJava is good for this type of structures, but I don'w know how to build this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Generally, such app can get quite complicated but here is a simple demonstration how the stream could be assembled:

```
public class MultiSourcePaged {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<String> localDatabase = Observable.empty();
        PublishSubject<String> externalSource = PublishSubject.create();
        Observable<String> serverDatabase = Observable.just("a", "b", "c");

        Observable<String> messages = Observable.merge(
            // use local database or switch to server
            localDatabase.switchIfEmpty(serverDatabase), 
            // merge in messages from outside
            externalSource.onBackpressureBuffer()
        );

        UISubscriber s = new UISubscriber();
        messages.subscribe(s);
        System.out.println("Retrieveing the first page...");
        s.requestMore(2);
        externalSource.onNext("d");
        externalSource.onNext("e");
        externalSource.onNext("f");
        System.out.println("Retrieveing the second page...");
        s.requestMore(2);
        externalSource.onCompleted();
        System.out.println("Retrieveing the third page...");
        s.requestMore(2);
        System.out.println("Retrieveing the fourth page...");
        s.requestMore(2);
    }
    static final class UISubscriber extends Subscriber<String> {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            request(0);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNext(String t) {
            System.out.println("Message: " + t);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("No more messages!");
        }
        public void requestMore(long n) {
            request(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great insight, will try this approach.

Comment: Can you explain this method request(n); in Subscriber. What it should include? (query, or something else?)

Comment: That requests n more elements from the stream.